# Is it possible to write to two separate data files at the same time in Python?

Tags: python, numpy

I am writing a piece of code where I need to write data to two separate data files at the same time. however this doesnt seem possible because when i close one they both close. There is probably an easier way of saving my data and stripping it of its brackets with out writing it to a file but I'm not aware of it. Here is my code:

```
datafile=open('new.txt', 'w')
extension = np.arange(1,3)
for ext in extension:
        if ext < 10:
            ext = '0'+str(ext)
        else:
            ext = str(ext)
        starfile=drcat+'DECam_00187567_'+ext+'_star_catalog.fits'
        #print starfile


    xc = pf.getdata(starfile).XWIN_IMAGE
    yc = pf.getdata(starfile).YWIN_IMAGE
    rmag = pf.getdata(starfile).MAG_AUTO
    stamp=getStamp(data=data,xcoord=xc,ycoord=yc,Npix =25)
    zz=len(stamp)
    print "stamp length=", zz

        kool=np.arange(0,zz)
    print kool
    datafile=open(str(ext)+'temp.txt', 'w')
    for lol in kool:
        b=stamp[lol]
        name=drstamp+str(ext)+'_'+str(lol)+'_stamp.fits' #write every stamp to a file
        sigma=1.1/0.27
            a=complexMoments(b, sigma)
        datafile.write(str(a)+'\n') # I want this to write to str(ext)+'temp.txt'
    datafile.close()

    """find the mean ellipicity for one image"""
    com=['cat ', str(ext)+"temp.txt " """| tr -d "s/,()*//g"> """ +str(ext)+"_temp.txt"]
    s0=''
    com=s0.join(com)
    print com
    res=os.system(com) #this stips the code of its brackets and commas, is there an easier way of doing this?


    ellipicity=np.genfromtxt(str(ext)+'_temp.txt').T[0]
    print ellipicity
    meanellip=np.mean(ellipicity)
    print "mean ellipicity=",meanellip
    print "\n"
    datafile.write(str(meanellip)+'\n')## I want this to write to new.txt
datafile.close()
```

So basically towards the end of my code I need to write meanellip to a data file (new.txt) but If I open the datafile inside the loop it opens it everytime and rewrites over its self. is there a way I can make each datafile.write correspond to a certain datafile? If not is there a better method I could use to achieve the meanellip for all of the data.

Comment: Just use _different variables_.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One variable for one object (one file, in this case). Think about it the next time :)

Comment: Yeah, I feel like a such an idiot right now. Thank you

Comment: Don't worry, I think it's a common mistake when you're not used with Python :)